# Prove that the Kullback-Leibler divergence is indeed a divergence

Tags: differential-geometry, divergence-operator

According to [1], $D[P\colon Q]$ is called a *divergence* if it satisfies the following criteria:

1. $D[P:Q] \geqslant 0$
2. $D[P:Q] =0 \iff P=Q$
3. When $P$ and $Q$ are sufficiently close, by denoting their coordinates by $\xi_p$ and $\xi_q=\xi_p + d\xi$, the Taylor expansion of $D$ is written as:
   $$
   D[\mathbf{\xi}_p\colon\xi_p+\xi] =
   \dfrac{1}{2}\sum g_{ij}(\xi_p)d\xi_id\xi_j + \mathcal{O}\left(\lvert\xi\lvert^3\right),
   $$
   where $g_{ij}$ denotes the $(i,j)$-th element of a positive definite matrix $G$ that depends on $\xi_p$.

I am trying to prove that the so-called *Kullback-Leibler divergence*, which is given as
$$
D_{KL}[p(x)\colon q(x)] = \int p(x)\log{\left(\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}\right)\mathrm{d}x}
$$
is indeed a *divergence*, based on the above definition, but I have been stuck at the $3^{rd}$ criterion.

Could you please give me some insight on how I should proceed?

[1] Amari, S. I. (2016). Information geometry and its applications (Vol. 194). Japan: Springer

Comment: This is [shown here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51185/connection-between-fisher-metric-and-the-relative-entropy) for the *symmetrized* KL divergence